# request for member 'nama' in something not a structure or union

Tags: c

so i have this code, but when im running it, it's shows that "error : request for member 'nama' in something not a structure or union.
this is an admin program when you buy a movie ticket, and the modul need the name of the admin to print it in the ticket

```
struct admin
{
    char nama[100];
    char id[100];
    char password[100];
};

struct admin pengatur[100];
ModeAdmin(pengatur[counter]);

void ModeAdmin(struct admin *c)
{
    struct admin pembuka;
    strcpy(pembuka.nama,c.nama);
    strcpy(pembuka.id,c.id);
    strcpy(pembuka.password,c.password);
    printf("Welcome %s",pembuka.nama);
    printf("1. Print Ticket\n");
    printf("2. Add New Film\n");
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of `struct admin`?

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add that

Comment: Change `c.` to `c->`. For example `c.nama` should be `c->nama`. `c->` is equivalent to `(*c).`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c` is a pointer to a struct, not a struct itself, so you can't use the `.` operator on it.  You need to instead use `->`, which dereferences the pointer and then gets the member:

```
strcpy(pembuka.nama,c->nama);
strcpy(pembuka.id,c->id);
strcpy(pembuka.password,c->password);
```

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
c.nama
```

should be:

```
c->nama
```

since `c` is not a struct or union, it's a pointer to a struct.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 strcpy(pembuka.nama,c.nama);
```

to

```
 strcpy(pembuka.nama,c->nama);
```

And all other occurences of `c.` likewise.

It is necessary because while `pembuka` is of type `struct admin`, `c` is only a pointer to one.

Comment: thank you Yunnosch